# credentials used by google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Currently have some confusion on the credentials/configuration used by dataflow...

From my experimentation, it seems that dataflow is always using the default configuration instead of the active configuration. Is that correct? (For example in my `gcloud config` if I have a default configuration with project A while my active configuration is on project B, it seems that my dataflow job will submit to project A always. Also in this way it seems that the dataflow job is ignoring what is set in `options.setProject()`, so sort of wondering when is dataflow using `options.getProject()` again...?)

And also wondering is there any way that I submit dataflow job with customized configuration, say I want to submit multiple jobs to different projects with different credentials on the same run(without manually changing my `gcloud config`)?

btw I am running the dataflow job on dataflow services cloud platform but submit the job from non-gce Cloudservices Account if it will make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

Google Cloud Dataflow by default uses the [application default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) library to get the credentials if they are not specified. The library currently only supports getting the credentials using the `gcloud` default configuration. Similarly, for the project, Google Cloud Dataflow uses the `gcloud` default configuration.

To be able to run jobs with a different project, one can manually specify on the command-line (for example `--project=myProject`, if using [PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/PipelineOptionsFactory.java#L162)) or set the option explicitly utilizing [GcpOptions.setProject](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/GcpOptions.java#L77).

To be able to run jobs with different credentials, one can construct a [credentials](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client/blob/dev/google-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential.java) object and can explicitly set it utilizing [GcpOptions.setGcpCredential](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/GcpOptions.java#L177) or one can rely on using the ways that the [application default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) library supports generating the credentials object automatically which Google Cloud Dataflow is tied into. One example would be to use the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork).

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thank you for the detailed answers! not sure whether i understand it correctly so just want to make sure: if i have set up project both in my default configuration and `GcpOptions`, in which project will my pipeline run and what will be the expect behavior in this circumstances again?

Comment: The values set on the various options classes will only be inferred if they are unset. Thus whatever value you set on GcpOptions will be honored and the default configuration for project will be ignored. Note, that if you only set the project, the credentials will still be inferred from the default configuration.

Comment: Hi @LukaszCwik I just tried to set credentials from a service account using the GcpOptions.setGcpCredential method.
`options.setGcpCredential(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json")));
options.setServiceAccount("xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com");`
When doing this, I'm asked to specify the scopes. Can I not just use the scopes to what this service account has permission to access? Maybe I am mixing up scopes and permissions here. Whenever I have this up and running I can add this as an answer or you can add this code :)

Comment: Scopes precede IAM accounts and are required to be specified until all Google services are IAM aware. Your best bet is to use the same set of scopes that Dataflow uses defined here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4c3174b80f4f359d4bb6f5c23011b811e0689895/sdks/java/extensions/google-cloud-platform-core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/auth/GcpCredentialFactory.java#L41

Comment: Awesome, that worked for me @LukaszCwik. I'll add my code as an answer for future reference, hope it helps people out :)

Answer (score 1):

The code I used to have Dataflow populate its workers with the service account we wanted (in addition to Lukas answer above):

```
final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub");
options.setGcpCredential(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json")).createScoped(SCOPES));
options.setServiceAccount("xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Took forever to find this. Don't know why this isn't documented well enough