# The tempLocation of Google Cloud Storage in self-executing DataFlow jar

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I exported DataFlow application to Runnable JAR file from Eclipse.
I get below exception when I run the command Desktop$java -jar mariadevconn.jar 
Why is the current working directory of command line added to the Google Storage path? Thank you for your help.

```
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions$StagingLocationFactory create
INFO: No stagingLocation provided, falling back to gcpTempLocation
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:142)
    at com.masterconcept.cloud.dataflow.connector.MariaDBConnector.main(MariaDBConnector.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a valid 'gs://' path but was given '/Users/henry/Desktop/gs:/hellodataflowfromhenry/temp/staging/'
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.getGcsPath(GcsPathValidator.java:101)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPath(GcsPathValidator.java:75)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(GcsPathValidator.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:237)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid GCS URI: /Users/henry/Desktop/gs:/hellodataflowfromhenry/temp/staging/
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.gcsfs.GcsPath.fromUri(GcsPath.java:116)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.getGcsPath(GcsPathValidator.java:99)
    ... 12 more
```

Part of the code:

```
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(argv).withValidation().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://hellodataflowfromhenry/temp");
options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
....
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

work directory:

```
Desktop$pwd
/Users/henry/Desktop
```

Comment: I solved this question, I use mvn in command line to export jar then it works.

Comment: reference links for this: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881851/credentials-used-by-google-cloud-dataflow 2) https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4c3174b80f4f359d4bb6f5c23011b811e0689895/sdks/java/extensions/google-cloud-platform-core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/auth/GcpCredentialFactory.java#L41